# Optimal data struct for k-k-v mapping

Tags: dictionary, data-structures, data-retrieval

I have a large mapping table with 1.4 billion records. The data struct is now like `{<Key1, Key2>: List<Value>}`.

`Key1` and `Value` are from same set, let's say `A`, with ~0.1 billion unique elements.

`Key2` are from another set, let's say `B`, with only 32 unique elements.

`List<Value>` is variable length list with up to 200 maximum elements.

Can someone recommend any better data structure or retrieval algorithm for quick online retrieval and proper space consumption.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an extendible hash table for this:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extendible_hashing

If you don't want to implement it yourself, then you could try using something like Redis or Memcached to serve as an external implementation of a persistable hash table.

To create the hashing key, just combine Key1 and Key2 (concatenate? xor?) and use that as a hash key.

If in RAM use a hash table with a dynamic array for your list. That should work well.

Unless you care about the order of the keys, hash tables should do the job.

If you want to get all Key1s associated to a Key2 you can do that as well by maintaining a separate hash table for that. Or if you're actually implementing this you could link the keys so that all keys that have Key2 in them, form a linked list.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Since key1 and values are from the same set, is there any bonus we can get from this relationship?

Comment: what kind of bonus are you looking for? less space? faster performance?
I think in a real world application keeping it simple is a great bonus. Because sophisticated code is hard to debug and get right. So whatever cool trickery you introduce better be worth it.